# Is it possible to set multiple functions for one onkeypress event

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
signin_input.onkeypress = function()
{
    label.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

but sometimes I want to run additional code so I overwrite it with this:

```
signin_input.onkeypress = function( event ) 
{
    signin_label.style.opacity = 0; // just add in previous function here
    if( event.keyCode === 13 )
    {
        new ControlType( 'signin' ).invoke();
        return false; 
    }
}
```

and just include the one line from the old function in the new function.

However, this is a bit inefficient as I write to onkeypress twice.

Is there a way to have both run.  Is there some sort of internal JavaScript construct that would allow this.

Comment: HA? can you make it a little more clear please.

Comment: @gdoron, he wants multiple callbacks on a single event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start reading about DOM events...setting properties of elements is the ancient way...use `addEventListener()` or `removeEventListener()` for **normal** (meaning not IE family). Or use `attachEvent()` or `detachEvent()` for IE6 ( and I suppose IE7 too )

Best way...use some js library, I recommend jQuery.

Comment: well...i'd like to confess that I am biased against the IE family itself...don't know why but it's just that way...hehe...as you said, IE8 and IE9 work fine (it pains a lot to say this ;)

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are doing something like this:

```
signin_input.onkeypress = function1;
signin_input.onkeypress = function2;
```

You could do something like this:

```
signin_input.onkeypress = function(){
    if (condition1) function1();
    if (condition2) function2();
};
```

Comment: Thanks...nice code...I will use this if I can not find and internal way....I don't think there is one...so this is likely the best fit.

Comment: Actually using addEventListener allows one to set multiple functions..but it might not have wide compatibility...have to look into...per above answer